# Why is $H$ the standard notation for mean curvature?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ho.history-overview, terminology, curves-and-surfaces, notation

I am curious about the origin of the notation $H$ to denote the mean curvature of a surface in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

I suppose that the symbol $K$, which is commonly used to denote the Gaussian curvature, comes from the German word "Krümmung", which means curvature. However, I cannot find any explanation as to why we use $H$ for the mean curvature. Does anybody know?

EDIT: As indicated in the comments, the question already appeared on MSE; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3299184/242708).

Comment: I looked at Sophie Germain's [Mémoire sur la courbure des surfaces](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783112389348-001/pdf), but she does not use any definite symbol for the mean curvature. Since Huygens pioneered much of the early study of curvature, let's say that the H is in his honour.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3299184/why-is-the-mean-curvature-usually-denoted-by-h). It is always a good idea to Google your own question first!

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda Thanks for the pointer! I did Google the question before posting, but apparently I did not search well enough. Nevertheless the question remains unanswered.

Comment: @MK7 I think the pattern $E, F, G, H$, as suggested in a comment in that question, is very suggestive. Either way I think this question is a better fit for [hsm](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).